# Modify states from a non react.component class

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-component

In my file I have a `Main` class which extends React.Component. The class is exported at the end of the file. It has some states, one of which is a list (Object[]).
Within the file there is another class (let's call it `Foo`) which has other functions. I create a reference to `Foo` within `Main`, and then use that to call `bar()` within `Foo`.
In `bar`, I have a for loop which should add 5 `TestComponents` to that list mentioned above.
Since it's a state, I also have `Foo` extending `React.Component`. The issue is that even though that allows me to use `setState()`, the component is never mounted so when you modify the state you get:

```
Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Foo component.
```

If I remove the `extends React.Component` from `Foo` then of course, I can't change the state since I can't use `setState`.
Here is a very simplified version of my main code:

```js
interface State {
    list: Object[];
}

class Main extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    foo = new Foo();

    state = {
      list: [],
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.list); //logs: []

    this.foo.bar();

    console.log(this.state.list); //logs: [] expected: [TestComponent....]

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <IonContent>
          <IonList>
              {
                  //this.list.map(...);
              }
          </IonList>
      </IonContent>
    );
  };
};

class Foo extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    state = {
        list: [],
    } 
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     console.log("mounted"); //doesnt log this since component doesnt get mounted
   }
   
  bar() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let a = <TestComponent key={i}></TestComponent>
      
      this.setState({
        list: [...this.state.list, a], //errors here saying component not mounted
      });

    }
  }
}
export default Main;
```

How can I modify the `list` state from within `Foo` since `Foo` is never mounted as a component ('mounted' is never logged)?
I tried seeing if a render function would mount it but like I thought it didn't.

```js
render() {
      return(
          <></>
      );
  }
```

Comment: What is your goal with this? Are you trying to have Foo be the host of some reusable code? The purpose of calling `setState` is to rerender a component, but the Foo component is never rendered in the first place (because no parent component returns `<Foo />` in its render method). From  your comments, it seems you expect that calling `this.foo.bar()` will update the state in *Main*, but that's not possible since inside the `bar` function, `this` refers to the Foo component, not the Main component.

Comment: It's for bluetooth. I create a Bluetooth class (Foo) and look for devices. The data of devices are used to create custom component (a list-item). This array full of list items is mapped into the ion-list. I have them in two classes and I needed a way to access the array from one class in another (and I thought states would be good). My main goal is to be able to have this list accesable globally. So not just from within 1 file, but every file (since I need the devices on every page of my app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work using globals (this *should* solve two problems at once. I needed the array 'global' within a single script but also within every script)

I did this by creating a globals.tsx file.
Within the file I added:

```js
export var bluetoothDevices: Object[] = [];
```

then to access it the global you can do:

```
import { bluetoothDevices }  from '/globals/globals'

bluetoothDevices.push(x);
```

and it's as simple as just pushing anything to the array. I can confirm this works within the file (I can modify and read it from each class) although I can't confirm if it works throughout all scripts since I only have 1 page at the moment.